# Trying to run multiple line cmd command inside my asp.net console app raised the following error "StandardIn has not been redirected"

Tags: c#, asp.net, cmd, console-application

I have the following code inside my asp.net console application:-

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("nslookup");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("set type=mx");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(domainname);

process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
Console.WriteLine("output>>" + e.Data);
process.BeginOutputReadLine();

process.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
Console.WriteLine("error>>" + e.Data);
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

process.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: {0}", process.ExitCode);
process.Close();
```

where i am trying to run the following commands and get the results:-

```
nslookup
set type=mx
domainname
```

but when the code reaches this line `process.StandardInput.WriteLine("nslookup");` i got this exception `StandardIn has not been redirected`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error is pretty descriptive: `StandardIn has not been redirected`

You have redirected stderr and stdout in the lines:

```
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

But as the error says you have *not* redirected `StandardIn`

You can do that by redirecting stdin with:

```
processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```